# How to run scripts from github on ubuntu

Tags: scripts, github

I am supposed to run a script Microsoft has provided for installing .net core to make sure I get rid of any version I already have, and the script is from github. How do I run it?

I need to do Step 2 from [this page](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#ubuntu)

I don't have github installed on my computer, but I am not sure if I need it?

Comment: It says I should run that script to check for any previous versions before I sudo apt-get install..

Comment: yeah but if you did not install it before no need for the script and skip it. In general: you download the script, make it executable  (hint:`chmod`) and execute it ;-)

Comment: okay so this a fresh install of ubuntu 16.04, do I need to even bother running it then?

Comment: no you don't :)

Comment: oh and all the script does is  `sudo apt-get purge -y dotnet-host` so you can also just copy that command over to a command line and execute it

Comment: okay thanks for the answer btw for the next time when I need it!

Comment: To the best of my knowledge: In order to remove the previous installation, simply remove the dotnet folder from where you installed it on disk. From http://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/4088

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to install anything. Follow the link to the script on GitHub and on the page it takes you to click the "Raw" tab on the right hand side above the script [(or just click here for the raw page)](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dotnet/cli/rel/1.0.0/scripts/obtain/uninstall/dotnet-uninstall-debian-packages.sh)

This takes you to a page with only the script. Copy all the text on the screen

Open your favourite text editor, for example, gedit, and paste the text there. Save it, with a name, let's say `netcore` Save it in your home directory or wherever you like. Then close the editor. Open a terminal, and give the script execute permission (replace with the name of the script)

```
chmod +x netcore
```

if you saved it somewhere other than home, you need to `cd` to the directory, for example, `cd Desktop` then `chmod +x netcore`

Run the script:

```
sudo ./netcore
```